# Dynamic request binding in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I was wondering if it is possible a dynamic binding according to a specific field.

example:

Usually, we may have a custom request injected to the controller like: `App\Http\Requests\CustomRequest`

However, I needed to instantiate another request according to a input field, for example:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
   switch($request->input('flag_field')) {
      case 'custom_request_1':
          // find some way to have the CustomRequest1 instance
          break;
      case 'custom_request_2':
          // find some way to have the CustomRequest2 instance
          break;
   }
}
```

Of course, it is a pretty ugly way to handle it and I'd like not to do it.

Does anyone know some other way? Maybe something like service binding or something like that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll suggest extend Request and move this logic in that class.

Comment: wouldn't it be a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better way to make it. I changed the `Request` class for an interface (`RequestInterface`) and bound it in the `AppServiceProvider` register method.

Controller class:

```
public function someAction(RequestInterface $request)
{
}
```

Provider class:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(RequestInterface::class, function ($app) {
        switch ($app->make('request')->input('flag_field')) {
                case 'custom_request_1':
                    return $app->make(CustomRequest1::class);
                    break;
                case 'custom_request_2':
                    return $app->make(CustomRequest2::class);
                    break;
    });
}
```

Comment: Something tells me this is a badly designed process with that king of overhead.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a better solution. If you have any idea, please, share with us

Comment: What you're doing is almost correct, but the flag field idea is now, i'm going to need more information about your actual goal, both requests and their differences.

Comment: My real problem is that I have a multi-step route intended to create a single resource. So it's registered like this: `resource/create/{step}`. This makes my controller to have a big switch with a rule for every single step and my goal is remove it in a clean way

Comment: Personally, I would physically create the end-points for your steps, and have a FormRequest for each as you were, but not requiring that flag field?